# I am out of shape, what exercises should I use for a brief calisthenic workout in the morning?

Tags: health, calisthenics

Following on [this question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13939/is-it-possible-to-gain-health-benefits-by-following-a-calisthenics-routine-for-a), I want to "design" a brief calisthenic workout, within my capabilities and possible to follow, to be done in the morning (let's say before the rest of the family wakes up).

Assume that I can touch the point of my toes and that the majority if not all of my physical exercise comes from playing with a 2 years old kid who is always willing to run and play. If it is needed, I am 1.82 m tall and weight in the 80-85 kg range (depending on the amount of stress at work and wheter I am able to restrain myself or not).

My goal is to improve my health: I don't expect miracles. I know that I should improve my diet and my life style. But those are not easy tasks and I would like to at least try do to something concrete.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the old and famous [5BX progressive program](http://gregsadetsky.com/_files/5bx-plan.pdf) developed in the 60s by the Royal Canadian Air Force and tested by many during decades. It was ment to keep in shape their staff in all kind of places an situations, by means of a daily 11 min program that could be performed in a dorm. Quoting from [its Wikipedia entry](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/5BX):

> The 5BX Plan is composed of six charts arranged in increasing order of difficulty. Each chart is composed of five exercises that are performed within 11 minutes. The first four exercises are calisthenics, and the last an aerobic exercise. As the individual progresses within the system, the number of each type of exercise that must be performed increases and the difficulty of each exercise increases.

Answer (score 1):

I just also recommended 5BX to someone in another thread, Don't be intimidated by the military title and think that it's going to exercise you into the ground very quickly. It has exercises and progressions suitable to everyone from 6 year olds to senior citizens to elite level athletes.